# How to refer script in sitemaster

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I know in mvc the site master page shares resource(html elements) with aspx file.Like this  it is possible to refer the script file in site master that will share with aspx?If so how to do that?

In other word am using script file in all my aspx.
`<script src="../../../Src/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Whether it is possible to refer in  my sitemaster page that will make that script reference in all my aspx?(Excluding my apsx page)

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Write in sitemaster scriptblock

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
```

and all your aspx pages that has this master will use this reference.

Comment: Actually i have number of slash in my script line in the meantime how can i use it? Thanks

Comment: You need to write path from masterpage.